# Enter/exit not properly cleaning up popped nodes/links in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I tried to graph a directed acyclic graph as a force layout.

I noticed however that in spite of instilling an enter/exit condition for every group element, popped nodes/links do not remove themselves from the DOM.

Rather, the popped nodes/links freeze in the force layout; which means that the enter/exit conditions are not being called to remove the popped nodes/links.

I isolated the code into a jsfiddle and stack snippet which will add and remove new nodes/links from the data after 3 seconds to showcase the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/dLucxt50/

```js
const nodes = [{
  "id": "b81c3b33da0295e5348979588322fcf1481b1f42f02ff3dd18ab1460d6deb297"
}, {
  "id": "b3b3c83724d14341ac4695d322641eeda1085946f08d3184ffcef87000385fc2"
}, {
  "id": "dbd7f209f0d595962b773fd6ae41827db5bfa8957790c0ca9f5a625a7d02ca66"
}, {
  "id": "9b35eccc52a58056a9ff76cabdd913b38938aa712315d04e1ed642cbe4dcd029"
}, {
  "id": "b9dc57db643aa8600c1fff4bf1951086749e33a2767e06050240648c450b5e58"
}, {
  "id": "7591a2b33553351aef3c232d89aa91e4aec10e310a0a19a032fcf4077463ab09"
}, {
  "id": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6"
}, {
  "id": "f9c716634ab8ea40745b53f67ed809d3beb1db4870a6f95613b0be7b14f05f55"
}, {
  "id": "993958aa99dd2dab952d8b358f64829ec69a0574f6b252ee34ebeee418f5b8e7"
}, {
  "id": "fd3b3b1dff7b32b24644a2855e9afae06008f54cc5dd2806dd628952a8fd1746"
}, {
  "id": "a1958f9fa30e423a895a8c31ffb44fbb46645eb03f571503ce4667b9f44be2f0"
}, {
  "id": "6ede9396d5a3a584a7a3611b113785d2c6bde95006ce90c1f389565e7e1e522c"
}, {
  "id": "7fe4b1ba43264c2ddb70996dff94b2aeb25b59a6e07b359bb1f6e80c7434369f"
}, {
  "id": "b35781d57d494e80e1552097cdc7473cc934d894af153b2dd37b9ef11d711ccc"
}, {
  "id": "87e5681a41244e93f9a9025442f4b5adabfd1de50f5381e4a52b5c2996d8c19d"
}, {
  "id": "6b13908162f818446312528603884d33b4c232a6230972706803daba4c3de027"
}, {
  "id": "fce4a71d30d20f3ded11f96c2260f1cd94eacd384305a31efe9ee2486edff6cc"
}, {
  "id": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d"
}, {
  "id": "1d64380cec09bb917a1ec7b7c8b9a72c69e64bccdf349b8a58432aef6d8c85f3"
}, {
  "id": "7740b97a1ba2728e7719d2a00d2690da0a994ff696ed37dc7c600a93a7a6ea18"
}, {
  "id": "9c8646ebc767c5f57ce3211e6c6728dbff28b41646438f9ec76ded8dee0bc91d"
}, {
  "id": "38ef2c3d22302d85ec5169271833fd636870eee59d2327835d1a9b2d5970b059"
}, {
  "id": "ed002f1ec48217437365ed6b739c634bbd47b329623126fc7f1c2bd9becb5aa4"
}, {
  "id": "9631a1fa6144d6b16e4aa0064e6e84ca7daf9f762d76561c98719798a8ff655d"
}, {
  "id": "1ea164a8140f621401e3015f1cb43d86e36495efacc6477c166ac0448d1ff51e"
}, {
  "id": "0fd71dbd018df0035e678b32cb2c327ab86974fa0b88aea95b4b115e4a083530"
}, {
  "id": "2758a86eb8b871b1cd9a897a8febabca2d21e17ada5f6b6b5e7da3333e66c171"
}, {
  "id": "d79f863cdc01f27c37586ffa37d53ac7663f98c2c02a7d122d9c89edb7374f96"
}, {
  "id": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e"
}, {
  "id": "e498742ffaac208feeea7fede7830a78c5e80844f64d70e1265efb86cdcd74ed"
}, {
  "id": "34cb8e9fc43571016ec74b739cfff6b0a1c2fd26b9ece1ea985ff00bb22eb220"
}, {
  "id": "bfa878cacfd97aae074bd8f123e89b5ee8e065533d220beb7d3270377a2aafb9"
}, {
  "id": "184ddbc88c1c543220336c9de05fbe6734015b18db6b19a8397bdeba67a8efeb"
}, {
  "id": "9424fd648818135e04522b22346223fa54eafa437f54def180999e3deb7405a9"
}, {
  "id": "2708216706f72320514ebddab7551eed03a6622d4a0067024c36940e353a7543"
}, {
  "id": "58b7882b4fa254f0115e88268cec08bc4327dab1d835b28b23c5748310f7f862"
}, {
  "id": "8dfcba1e98ca33746325f1c142851966defb2bdf2625f7ee45747ef0c84e218d"
}, {
  "id": "8a5d0543fe251def509c196562ecb036f4ff085e484b733298b5db5acc3f55e9"
}, {
  "id": "2aca0723448fdff7a6471bf18f83ff9bd1752dd9e1713c2e294bdc4e19e28e6b"
}, {
  "id": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4"
}, {
  "id": "29cd946900b47644a9237c886fcbf874c1a30e0f56a2d578ee65e9dc7cd697e6"
}, {
  "id": "8bd0e2628ff9047b1a41b5954ff68e9db5d3acb122cb9498d1c0066ad31c4ae6"
}, {
  "id": "17a34ac7de73cecd0a4e2dcefc97f8cd418c10d6aa1f0311b8c3f833b618d941"
}, {
  "id": "5dd24f315aeae358e4bcd6d17313929093550ac3e08c719485ce13e5c1a2c812"
}, {
  "id": "3958fe2700d4af2498094b2039d98b6ecc409c4196e322146910498d0b9c3ebe"
}, {
  "id": "520434ed7d42d6d732560288bfe21eb1f37db1bb176450d3f5a6d6ec32658cd5"
}, {
  "id": "91aae88c7358780cec9062d8bc200d59c29dca107dfd96862a68c86113a373a1"
}, {
  "id": "ac0c2ecdc6e53e55387df48d7b3457f5792392bcb7bfea0a56d096de19359a28"
}, {
  "id": "395aedb5ec6942b615ded5ad5b3aa538bed94a6479ed5c685d503b552e364043"
}, {
  "id": "37603e4d6de3c9b914c839bb5b90d4b5254e6e0f53d5587793c4ddec71de5775"
}, ]

let links = [{
  "source": "b81c3b33da0295e5348979588322fcf1481b1f42f02ff3dd18ab1460d6deb297",
  "target": "b3b3c83724d14341ac4695d322641eeda1085946f08d3184ffcef87000385fc2"
}, {
  "source": "b3b3c83724d14341ac4695d322641eeda1085946f08d3184ffcef87000385fc2",
  "target": "dbd7f209f0d595962b773fd6ae41827db5bfa8957790c0ca9f5a625a7d02ca66"
}, {
  "source": "dbd7f209f0d595962b773fd6ae41827db5bfa8957790c0ca9f5a625a7d02ca66",
  "target": "9b35eccc52a58056a9ff76cabdd913b38938aa712315d04e1ed642cbe4dcd029"
}, {
  "source": "9b35eccc52a58056a9ff76cabdd913b38938aa712315d04e1ed642cbe4dcd029",
  "target": "b9dc57db643aa8600c1fff4bf1951086749e33a2767e06050240648c450b5e58"
}, {
  "source": "b9dc57db643aa8600c1fff4bf1951086749e33a2767e06050240648c450b5e58",
  "target": "7591a2b33553351aef3c232d89aa91e4aec10e310a0a19a032fcf4077463ab09"
}, {
  "source": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6",
  "target": "f9c716634ab8ea40745b53f67ed809d3beb1db4870a6f95613b0be7b14f05f55"
}, {
  "source": "7591a2b33553351aef3c232d89aa91e4aec10e310a0a19a032fcf4077463ab09",
  "target": "f9c716634ab8ea40745b53f67ed809d3beb1db4870a6f95613b0be7b14f05f55"
}, {
  "source": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6",
  "target": "993958aa99dd2dab952d8b358f64829ec69a0574f6b252ee34ebeee418f5b8e7"
}, {
  "source": "f9c716634ab8ea40745b53f67ed809d3beb1db4870a6f95613b0be7b14f05f55",
  "target": "993958aa99dd2dab952d8b358f64829ec69a0574f6b252ee34ebeee418f5b8e7"
}, {
  "source": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6",
  "target": "fd3b3b1dff7b32b24644a2855e9afae06008f54cc5dd2806dd628952a8fd1746"
}, {
  "source": "993958aa99dd2dab952d8b358f64829ec69a0574f6b252ee34ebeee418f5b8e7",
  "target": "fd3b3b1dff7b32b24644a2855e9afae06008f54cc5dd2806dd628952a8fd1746"
}, {
  "source": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6",
  "target": "a1958f9fa30e423a895a8c31ffb44fbb46645eb03f571503ce4667b9f44be2f0"
}, {
  "source": "fd3b3b1dff7b32b24644a2855e9afae06008f54cc5dd2806dd628952a8fd1746",
  "target": "a1958f9fa30e423a895a8c31ffb44fbb46645eb03f571503ce4667b9f44be2f0"
}, {
  "source": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6",
  "target": "6ede9396d5a3a584a7a3611b113785d2c6bde95006ce90c1f389565e7e1e522c"
}, {
  "source": "a1958f9fa30e423a895a8c31ffb44fbb46645eb03f571503ce4667b9f44be2f0",
  "target": "6ede9396d5a3a584a7a3611b113785d2c6bde95006ce90c1f389565e7e1e522c"
}, {
  "source": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6",
  "target": "7fe4b1ba43264c2ddb70996dff94b2aeb25b59a6e07b359bb1f6e80c7434369f"
}, {
  "source": "6ede9396d5a3a584a7a3611b113785d2c6bde95006ce90c1f389565e7e1e522c",
  "target": "7fe4b1ba43264c2ddb70996dff94b2aeb25b59a6e07b359bb1f6e80c7434369f"
}, {
  "source": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6",
  "target": "b35781d57d494e80e1552097cdc7473cc934d894af153b2dd37b9ef11d711ccc"
}, {
  "source": "7fe4b1ba43264c2ddb70996dff94b2aeb25b59a6e07b359bb1f6e80c7434369f",
  "target": "b35781d57d494e80e1552097cdc7473cc934d894af153b2dd37b9ef11d711ccc"
}, {
  "source": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6",
  "target": "87e5681a41244e93f9a9025442f4b5adabfd1de50f5381e4a52b5c2996d8c19d"
}, {
  "source": "b35781d57d494e80e1552097cdc7473cc934d894af153b2dd37b9ef11d711ccc",
  "target": "87e5681a41244e93f9a9025442f4b5adabfd1de50f5381e4a52b5c2996d8c19d"
}, {
  "source": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6",
  "target": "6b13908162f818446312528603884d33b4c232a6230972706803daba4c3de027"
}, {
  "source": "87e5681a41244e93f9a9025442f4b5adabfd1de50f5381e4a52b5c2996d8c19d",
  "target": "6b13908162f818446312528603884d33b4c232a6230972706803daba4c3de027"
}, {
  "source": "bf3cc051afb459f8a392bcfa89619c348b6f0b676a46d827616b6d71eb253ac6",
  "target": "fce4a71d30d20f3ded11f96c2260f1cd94eacd384305a31efe9ee2486edff6cc"
}, {
  "source": "6b13908162f818446312528603884d33b4c232a6230972706803daba4c3de027",
  "target": "fce4a71d30d20f3ded11f96c2260f1cd94eacd384305a31efe9ee2486edff6cc"
}, {
  "source": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d",
  "target": "1d64380cec09bb917a1ec7b7c8b9a72c69e64bccdf349b8a58432aef6d8c85f3"
}, {
  "source": "fce4a71d30d20f3ded11f96c2260f1cd94eacd384305a31efe9ee2486edff6cc",
  "target": "1d64380cec09bb917a1ec7b7c8b9a72c69e64bccdf349b8a58432aef6d8c85f3"
}, {
  "source": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d",
  "target": "7740b97a1ba2728e7719d2a00d2690da0a994ff696ed37dc7c600a93a7a6ea18"
}, {
  "source": "1d64380cec09bb917a1ec7b7c8b9a72c69e64bccdf349b8a58432aef6d8c85f3",
  "target": "7740b97a1ba2728e7719d2a00d2690da0a994ff696ed37dc7c600a93a7a6ea18"
}, {
  "source": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d",
  "target": "9c8646ebc767c5f57ce3211e6c6728dbff28b41646438f9ec76ded8dee0bc91d"
}, {
  "source": "7740b97a1ba2728e7719d2a00d2690da0a994ff696ed37dc7c600a93a7a6ea18",
  "target": "9c8646ebc767c5f57ce3211e6c6728dbff28b41646438f9ec76ded8dee0bc91d"
}, {
  "source": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d",
  "target": "38ef2c3d22302d85ec5169271833fd636870eee59d2327835d1a9b2d5970b059"
}, {
  "source": "9c8646ebc767c5f57ce3211e6c6728dbff28b41646438f9ec76ded8dee0bc91d",
  "target": "38ef2c3d22302d85ec5169271833fd636870eee59d2327835d1a9b2d5970b059"
}, {
  "source": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d",
  "target": "ed002f1ec48217437365ed6b739c634bbd47b329623126fc7f1c2bd9becb5aa4"
}, {
  "source": "38ef2c3d22302d85ec5169271833fd636870eee59d2327835d1a9b2d5970b059",
  "target": "ed002f1ec48217437365ed6b739c634bbd47b329623126fc7f1c2bd9becb5aa4"
}, {
  "source": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d",
  "target": "9631a1fa6144d6b16e4aa0064e6e84ca7daf9f762d76561c98719798a8ff655d"
}, {
  "source": "ed002f1ec48217437365ed6b739c634bbd47b329623126fc7f1c2bd9becb5aa4",
  "target": "9631a1fa6144d6b16e4aa0064e6e84ca7daf9f762d76561c98719798a8ff655d"
}, {
  "source": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d",
  "target": "1ea164a8140f621401e3015f1cb43d86e36495efacc6477c166ac0448d1ff51e"
}, {
  "source": "9631a1fa6144d6b16e4aa0064e6e84ca7daf9f762d76561c98719798a8ff655d",
  "target": "1ea164a8140f621401e3015f1cb43d86e36495efacc6477c166ac0448d1ff51e"
}, {
  "source": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d",
  "target": "0fd71dbd018df0035e678b32cb2c327ab86974fa0b88aea95b4b115e4a083530"
}, {
  "source": "1ea164a8140f621401e3015f1cb43d86e36495efacc6477c166ac0448d1ff51e",
  "target": "0fd71dbd018df0035e678b32cb2c327ab86974fa0b88aea95b4b115e4a083530"
}, {
  "source": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d",
  "target": "2758a86eb8b871b1cd9a897a8febabca2d21e17ada5f6b6b5e7da3333e66c171"
}, {
  "source": "0fd71dbd018df0035e678b32cb2c327ab86974fa0b88aea95b4b115e4a083530",
  "target": "2758a86eb8b871b1cd9a897a8febabca2d21e17ada5f6b6b5e7da3333e66c171"
}, {
  "source": "924f5473366ae03f1f4c5c7ecd03a09d976982dbca67e1ee65457e661b17c49d",
  "target": "d79f863cdc01f27c37586ffa37d53ac7663f98c2c02a7d122d9c89edb7374f96"
}, {
  "source": "2758a86eb8b871b1cd9a897a8febabca2d21e17ada5f6b6b5e7da3333e66c171",
  "target": "d79f863cdc01f27c37586ffa37d53ac7663f98c2c02a7d122d9c89edb7374f96"
}, {
  "source": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e",
  "target": "e498742ffaac208feeea7fede7830a78c5e80844f64d70e1265efb86cdcd74ed"
}, {
  "source": "d79f863cdc01f27c37586ffa37d53ac7663f98c2c02a7d122d9c89edb7374f96",
  "target": "e498742ffaac208feeea7fede7830a78c5e80844f64d70e1265efb86cdcd74ed"
}, {
  "source": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e",
  "target": "34cb8e9fc43571016ec74b739cfff6b0a1c2fd26b9ece1ea985ff00bb22eb220"
}, {
  "source": "e498742ffaac208feeea7fede7830a78c5e80844f64d70e1265efb86cdcd74ed",
  "target": "34cb8e9fc43571016ec74b739cfff6b0a1c2fd26b9ece1ea985ff00bb22eb220"
}, {
  "source": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e",
  "target": "bfa878cacfd97aae074bd8f123e89b5ee8e065533d220beb7d3270377a2aafb9"
}, {
  "source": "34cb8e9fc43571016ec74b739cfff6b0a1c2fd26b9ece1ea985ff00bb22eb220",
  "target": "bfa878cacfd97aae074bd8f123e89b5ee8e065533d220beb7d3270377a2aafb9"
}, {
  "source": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e",
  "target": "184ddbc88c1c543220336c9de05fbe6734015b18db6b19a8397bdeba67a8efeb"
}, {
  "source": "bfa878cacfd97aae074bd8f123e89b5ee8e065533d220beb7d3270377a2aafb9",
  "target": "184ddbc88c1c543220336c9de05fbe6734015b18db6b19a8397bdeba67a8efeb"
}, {
  "source": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e",
  "target": "9424fd648818135e04522b22346223fa54eafa437f54def180999e3deb7405a9"
}, {
  "source": "184ddbc88c1c543220336c9de05fbe6734015b18db6b19a8397bdeba67a8efeb",
  "target": "9424fd648818135e04522b22346223fa54eafa437f54def180999e3deb7405a9"
}, {
  "source": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e",
  "target": "2708216706f72320514ebddab7551eed03a6622d4a0067024c36940e353a7543"
}, {
  "source": "9424fd648818135e04522b22346223fa54eafa437f54def180999e3deb7405a9",
  "target": "2708216706f72320514ebddab7551eed03a6622d4a0067024c36940e353a7543"
}, {
  "source": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e",
  "target": "58b7882b4fa254f0115e88268cec08bc4327dab1d835b28b23c5748310f7f862"
}, {
  "source": "2708216706f72320514ebddab7551eed03a6622d4a0067024c36940e353a7543",
  "target": "58b7882b4fa254f0115e88268cec08bc4327dab1d835b28b23c5748310f7f862"
}, {
  "source": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e",
  "target": "8dfcba1e98ca33746325f1c142851966defb2bdf2625f7ee45747ef0c84e218d"
}, {
  "source": "58b7882b4fa254f0115e88268cec08bc4327dab1d835b28b23c5748310f7f862",
  "target": "8dfcba1e98ca33746325f1c142851966defb2bdf2625f7ee45747ef0c84e218d"
}, {
  "source": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e",
  "target": "8a5d0543fe251def509c196562ecb036f4ff085e484b733298b5db5acc3f55e9"
}, {
  "source": "8dfcba1e98ca33746325f1c142851966defb2bdf2625f7ee45747ef0c84e218d",
  "target": "8a5d0543fe251def509c196562ecb036f4ff085e484b733298b5db5acc3f55e9"
}, {
  "source": "a3817823b2c12239b034a76f7e1208556ea37833b1b0831e0659ba21c6ecc55e",
  "target": "2aca0723448fdff7a6471bf18f83ff9bd1752dd9e1713c2e294bdc4e19e28e6b"
}, {
  "source": "8a5d0543fe251def509c196562ecb036f4ff085e484b733298b5db5acc3f55e9",
  "target": "2aca0723448fdff7a6471bf18f83ff9bd1752dd9e1713c2e294bdc4e19e28e6b"
}, {
  "source": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
  "target": "29cd946900b47644a9237c886fcbf874c1a30e0f56a2d578ee65e9dc7cd697e6"
}, {
  "source": "2aca0723448fdff7a6471bf18f83ff9bd1752dd9e1713c2e294bdc4e19e28e6b",
  "target": "29cd946900b47644a9237c886fcbf874c1a30e0f56a2d578ee65e9dc7cd697e6"
}, {
  "source": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
  "target": "8bd0e2628ff9047b1a41b5954ff68e9db5d3acb122cb9498d1c0066ad31c4ae6"
}, {
  "source": "29cd946900b47644a9237c886fcbf874c1a30e0f56a2d578ee65e9dc7cd697e6",
  "target": "8bd0e2628ff9047b1a41b5954ff68e9db5d3acb122cb9498d1c0066ad31c4ae6"
}, {
  "source": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
  "target": "17a34ac7de73cecd0a4e2dcefc97f8cd418c10d6aa1f0311b8c3f833b618d941"
}, {
  "source": "8bd0e2628ff9047b1a41b5954ff68e9db5d3acb122cb9498d1c0066ad31c4ae6",
  "target": "17a34ac7de73cecd0a4e2dcefc97f8cd418c10d6aa1f0311b8c3f833b618d941"
}, {
  "source": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
  "target": "5dd24f315aeae358e4bcd6d17313929093550ac3e08c719485ce13e5c1a2c812"
}, {
  "source": "17a34ac7de73cecd0a4e2dcefc97f8cd418c10d6aa1f0311b8c3f833b618d941",
  "target": "5dd24f315aeae358e4bcd6d17313929093550ac3e08c719485ce13e5c1a2c812"
}, {
  "source": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
  "target": "3958fe2700d4af2498094b2039d98b6ecc409c4196e322146910498d0b9c3ebe"
}, {
  "source": "5dd24f315aeae358e4bcd6d17313929093550ac3e08c719485ce13e5c1a2c812",
  "target": "3958fe2700d4af2498094b2039d98b6ecc409c4196e322146910498d0b9c3ebe"
}, {
  "source": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
  "target": "520434ed7d42d6d732560288bfe21eb1f37db1bb176450d3f5a6d6ec32658cd5"
}, {
  "source": "3958fe2700d4af2498094b2039d98b6ecc409c4196e322146910498d0b9c3ebe",
  "target": "520434ed7d42d6d732560288bfe21eb1f37db1bb176450d3f5a6d6ec32658cd5"
}, {
  "source": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
  "target": "91aae88c7358780cec9062d8bc200d59c29dca107dfd96862a68c86113a373a1"
}, {
  "source": "520434ed7d42d6d732560288bfe21eb1f37db1bb176450d3f5a6d6ec32658cd5",
  "target": "91aae88c7358780cec9062d8bc200d59c29dca107dfd96862a68c86113a373a1"
}, {
  "source": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
  "target": "ac0c2ecdc6e53e55387df48d7b3457f5792392bcb7bfea0a56d096de19359a28"
}, {
  "source": "91aae88c7358780cec9062d8bc200d59c29dca107dfd96862a68c86113a373a1",
  "target": "ac0c2ecdc6e53e55387df48d7b3457f5792392bcb7bfea0a56d096de19359a28"
}, {
  "source": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
  "target": "395aedb5ec6942b615ded5ad5b3aa538bed94a6479ed5c685d503b552e364043"
}, {
  "source": "ac0c2ecdc6e53e55387df48d7b3457f5792392bcb7bfea0a56d096de19359a28",
  "target": "395aedb5ec6942b615ded5ad5b3aa538bed94a6479ed5c685d503b552e364043"
}, {
  "source": "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
  "target": "37603e4d6de3c9b914c839bb5b90d4b5254e6e0f53d5587793c4ddec71de5775"
}, {
  "source": "395aedb5ec6942b615ded5ad5b3aa538bed94a6479ed5c685d503b552e364043",
  "target": "37603e4d6de3c9b914c839bb5b90d4b5254e6e0f53d5587793c4ddec71de5775"
}]

const svg = d3.select("#graph")
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", () => networkGraph.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)));

const networkGraph = svg.append("g");

const width = 1000;
const height = 500;

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(this.nodes)
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(this.links).id((d) => d.id).distance(50).strength(1))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(4.5).iterations(4.5))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-120))
  .force("gravity", d3.forceManyBody().strength(30))
  .force("x", d3.forceX())
  .force("y", d3.forceY())
  .alphaTarget(1);

const drag = () => {
  const dragStarted = (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) {
      simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    }
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  const dragged = (d) => {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  const dragEnded = (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) {
      simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    }
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  };

  return d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragStarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragEnded);
}

let link = networkGraph.append("g").selectAll(".link");
let node = networkGraph.append("g").selectAll(".node");

const update = () => {
  // Spawn vertices.
  node = node.data(nodes, (d) => d.id);
  node.exit().remove();

  const newNodes = node.enter();
  const newNodesGroup = newNodes
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

  newNodesGroup.append("text")
  newNodesGroup.append("circle");

  // @ts-ignore
  node = newNodes.merge(node);

  const circle = node.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .call(drag());
  const label = node.selectAll("text")
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .text((d) => d.id);

  // Spawn edges.
  link = link.data(links, (d) => `${d.source} ${d.target}`);
  link.exit().remove();
  link = link.enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .merge(link);

  simulation.on("tick", () => {
    link
      .attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);

    circle
      .attr("cx", (d) => d.x)
      .attr("cy", (d) => d.y);

    label
      .attr("x", (d) => d.x + 8)
      .attr("y", (d) => d.y);
  });

  simulation.nodes(nodes);
  simulation.force("link").links(links);
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
}

update();

const pop = () => {
  let popped = nodes.shift();
  links = links.filter(l => l.source !== popped.id && l.target !== popped.id);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  pop();

  nodes.push({
    id: "29cd946900b47644a9237c886fcbf874c1a30e0f56a2d578ee65e9dc7cd697e6"
  })
  links.push({
    source: "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
    target: "29cd946900b47644a9237c886fcbf874c1a30e0f56a2d578ee65e9dc7cd697e6"
  })
  links.push({
    source: "2aca0723448fdff7a6471bf18f83ff9bd1752dd9e1713c2e294bdc4e19e28e6b",
    target: "29cd946900b47644a9237c886fcbf874c1a30e0f56a2d578ee65e9dc7cd697e6"
  })

  pop();

  nodes.push({
    id: "8bd0e2628ff9047b1a41b5954ff68e9db5d3acb122cb9498d1c0066ad31c4ae6"
  })
  links.push({
    source: "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
    target: "8bd0e2628ff9047b1a41b5954ff68e9db5d3acb122cb9498d1c0066ad31c4ae6"
  })
  links.push({
    source: "29cd946900b47644a9237c886fcbf874c1a30e0f56a2d578ee65e9dc7cd697e6",
    target: "8bd0e2628ff9047b1a41b5954ff68e9db5d3acb122cb9498d1c0066ad31c4ae6"
  })

  pop();

  nodes.push({
    id: "17a34ac7de73cecd0a4e2dcefc97f8cd418c10d6aa1f0311b8c3f833b618d941"
  })
  links.push({
    source: "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
    target: "17a34ac7de73cecd0a4e2dcefc97f8cd418c10d6aa1f0311b8c3f833b618d941"
  })
  links.push({
    source: "8bd0e2628ff9047b1a41b5954ff68e9db5d3acb122cb9498d1c0066ad31c4ae6",
    target: "17a34ac7de73cecd0a4e2dcefc97f8cd418c10d6aa1f0311b8c3f833b618d941"
  })

  pop();

  nodes.push({
    id: "5dd24f315aeae358e4bcd6d17313929093550ac3e08c719485ce13e5c1a2c812"
  })
  links.push({
    source: "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
    target: "5dd24f315aeae358e4bcd6d17313929093550ac3e08c719485ce13e5c1a2c812"
  })
  links.push({
    source: "17a34ac7de73cecd0a4e2dcefc97f8cd418c10d6aa1f0311b8c3f833b618d941",
    target: "5dd24f315aeae358e4bcd6d17313929093550ac3e08c719485ce13e5c1a2c812"
  })

  pop();

  nodes.push({
    id: "3958fe2700d4af2498094b2039d98b6ecc409c4196e322146910498d0b9c3ebe"
  })
  links.push({
    source: "78a93552bf3eb4239fc984a7baaeba7315b7208223516799d173f1fdf0519bf4",
    target: "3958fe2700d4af2498094b2039d98b6ecc409c4196e322146910498d0b9c3ebe"
  })
  links.push({
    source: "5dd24f315aeae358e4bcd6d17313929093550ac3e08c719485ce13e5c1a2c812",
    target: "3958fe2700d4af2498094b2039d98b6ecc409c4196e322146910498d0b9c3ebe"
  })

  update();
}, 3000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #30404d;
}

svg {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(16, 22, 26, 0.4);
  background: rgba(16, 22, 26, 0.3);
  color: #f5f8fa;
}

.link {
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-opacity: 0.3;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  display: none;
  font: 10px monospace;
  fill: white;
}

.node:hover circle {
  fill: #000;
}

.node:hover text {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <svg id="graph" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues, one each for nodes and links.

For nodes you need to merge the entered `g` (returned by `.enter().append("g")`) elements into the selection, not the placeholders (returned by `.enter()`). Otherwise you have a selection of placeholders in `node`, and exiting them won't do anything.

For links it is a bit more interesting.

A force layout alters the structure of your data, for nodes the data array items gain, if they don't already have them, `x`,`y`,`vx`,`vy`, and `index` properties.

For links, the links `source` and `target` properties become references to specific nodes/items in the nodes data array, not strings specifying ids. This is why we can use:

```
link
  .attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
  .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
  .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
  .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);
```

But, simultaneously that means we can't  use:

```
links = links.filter(l => l.source !== popped.id && l.target !== popped.id);
```

Since `l.source` and `l.target` will not be strings comparable to `popped.id` once we initialize the links, instead, we can use `l.source.id` and `l.target.id`.

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3s87wjy/)

And a snippet (modified ids so that it fits better):

```js
const nodes=[{"id":"a"},{"id":"b"},{"id":"c"},{"id":"d"},{"id":"e"},{"id":"f"},{"id":"g"},{"id":"h"},{"id":"i"},{"id":"j"},{"id":"k"},{"id":"l"},{"id":"m"},{"id":"n"},{"id":"o"},{"id":"p"},{"id":"q"},{"id":"r"},{"id":"s"},{"id":"t"},{"id":"u"},{"id":"v"},{"id":"w"},{"id":"x"},{"id":"y"},{"id":"z"},{"id":"aa"},{"id":"ab"},{"id":"ac"},{"id":"ad"},{"id":"ae"},{"id":"af"},{"id":"ag"},{"id":"ah"},{"id":"ai"},{"id":"aj2"},{"id":"ak"},{"id":"al"},{"id":"am"},{"id":"an"},{"id":"ao"},{"id":"ap"},{"id":"ar"},{"id":"aq"},{"id":"as"},{"id":"at"},{"id":"au"},{"id":"av"},{"id":"aw"},{"id":"ax"},]
let links=[{"source":"a","target":"b"},{"source":"b","target":"c"},{"source":"c","target":"d"},{"source":"d","target":"e"},{"source":"e","target":"f"},{"source":"g","target":"h"},{"source":"f","target":"h"},{"source":"g","target":"i"},{"source":"h","target":"i"},{"source":"g","target":"j"},{"source":"i","target":"j"},{"source":"g","target":"k"},{"source":"j","target":"k"},{"source":"g","target":"l"},{"source":"k","target":"l"},{"source":"g","target":"m"},{"source":"l","target":"m"},{"source":"g","target":"n"},{"source":"m","target":"n"},{"source":"g","target":"o"},{"source":"n","target":"o"},{"source":"g","target":"p"},{"source":"o","target":"p"},{"source":"g","target":"q"},{"source":"p","target":"q"},{"source":"r","target":"s"},{"source":"q","target":"s"},{"source":"r","target":"t"},{"source":"s","target":"t"},{"source":"r","target":"u"},{"source":"t","target":"u"},{"source":"r","target":"v"},{"source":"u","target":"v"},{"source":"r","target":"w"},{"source":"v","target":"w"},{"source":"r","target":"x"},{"source":"w","target":"x"},{"source":"r","target":"y"},{"source":"x","target":"y"},{"source":"r","target":"z"},{"source":"y","target":"z"},{"source":"r","target":"aa"},{"source":"z","target":"aa"},{"source":"r","target":"ab"},{"source":"aa","target":"ab"},{"source":"ac","target":"ad"},{"source":"ab","target":"ad"},{"source":"ac","target":"ae"},{"source":"ad","target":"ae"},{"source":"ac","target":"af"},{"source":"ae","target":"af"},{"source":"ac","target":"ag"},{"source":"af","target":"ag"},{"source":"ac","target":"ah"},{"source":"ag","target":"ah"},{"source":"ac","target":"ai"},{"source":"ah","target":"ai"},{"source":"ac","target":"aj2"},{"source":"ai","target":"aj2"},{"source":"ac","target":"ak"},{"source":"aj2","target":"ak"},{"source":"ac","target":"al"},{"source":"ak","target":"al"},{"source":"ac","target":"am"},{"source":"al","target":"am"},{"source":"an","target":"ao"},{"source":"am","target":"ao"},{"source":"an","target":"ap"},{"source":"ao","target":"ap"},{"source":"an","target":"ar"},{"source":"ap","target":"ar"},{"source":"an","target":"aq"},{"source":"ar","target":"aq"},{"source":"an","target":"as"},{"source":"aq","target":"as"},{"source":"an","target":"at"},{"source":"as","target":"at"},{"source":"an","target":"au"},{"source":"at","target":"au"},{"source":"an","target":"av"},{"source":"au","target":"av"},{"source":"an","target":"aw"},{"source":"av","target":"aw"},{"source":"an","target":"ax"},{"source":"aw","target":"ax"}]

const svg = d3.select("#graph")
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", () => networkGraph.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)));

const networkGraph = svg.append("g");

const width = 1000;
const height = 500;

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(this.nodes)
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(this.links).id((d) => d.id).distance(50).strength(1))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(4.5).iterations(4.5))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-120))
  .force("gravity", d3.forceManyBody().strength(30))
  .force("x", d3.forceX())
  .force("y", d3.forceY())
  .alphaTarget(1);

const drag = () => {
  const dragStarted = (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) {
      simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    }
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  const dragged = (d) => {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  const dragEnded = (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) {
      simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    }
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  };

  return d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragStarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragEnded);
}

let link = networkGraph.append("g").selectAll(".link");
let node = networkGraph.append("g").selectAll(".node");

const update = () => {
  // Spawn vertices.
  node = node.data(nodes, (d) => d.id);
  node.exit().remove();

  const newNodes = node.enter();
  const newNodesGroup = newNodes
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

  newNodesGroup.append("text")
  newNodesGroup.append("circle");

  // @ts-ignore
  node = newNodesGroup.merge(node);

  const circle = node.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .call(drag());
  const label = node.selectAll("text")
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .text((d) => d.id);

  // Spawn edges.
  link = link.data(links, (d) => `${d.source} ${d.target}`);
  link.exit().remove();
  link = link.enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .merge(link);

  simulation.on("tick", () => {
    link
      .attr("x1", (d) => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", (d) => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", (d) => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", (d) => d.target.y);

    circle
      .attr("cx", (d) => d.x)
      .attr("cy", (d) => d.y);

    label
      .attr("x", (d) => d.x + 8)
      .attr("y", (d) => d.y);
  });

  simulation.nodes(nodes);
  simulation.force("link").links(links);
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
}

update();

const pop = () => {
  let popped = nodes.shift();
  links = links.filter(l => l.source.id !== popped.id && l.target.id !== popped.id);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  pop();
  nodes.push({id: "ao2"})
  links.push({ source: "an", target: "ao2"})
  links.push({ source: "am", target: "ao2"})

  pop();
  nodes.push({ id: "ap2"})
  links.push({ source: "an",target: "ap2"})
  links.push({ source: "ao",target: "ap2"})

  pop();
  nodes.push({id: "ar2"})
  links.push({source: "an",target: "ar2"})
  links.push({source: "ap",target: "ar2"})
  
  pop();
  nodes.push({id: "aq2"})
  links.push({source: "an",target: "aq2"})
  links.push({source: "ar",target: "aq2"})

  pop();
  nodes.push({ id: "as2"})
  links.push({ source: "an", target: "as2"})
  links.push({source: "aq",target: "as2"})

  update();
}, 3000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #30404d;
}

svg {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(16, 22, 26, 0.4);
  background: rgba(16, 22, 26, 0.3);
  color: #f5f8fa;
}

.link {
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-opacity: 0.3;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  display: none;
  font: 10px monospace;
  fill: white;
}

.node:hover circle {
  fill: #000;
}

.node:hover text {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <svg id="graph" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"> </div>
</body>
```